# Hibernate's setParameterList is not working for Native SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
String Query = "Select name from Customer where city in (:city)";

Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ArrayList<String> city = new ArrayList<String>();
city.add("Bangalore");
city.add("Hyderabad");
values.put("city" , city);

... 

public List getResult(String query, Map<String, Object> values) {
    Session session = getSession(true);
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);

    if(!values.isEmpty()) {
          for (String key : values.keySet()) {
               Object value = values.get(key);

               if (value instanceof Collection) {
                    sqlQuery.setParameterList(key, (Collection) value);
               } else {
                    sqlQuery.setParameter(key, value);
               }
          }
      }

   return sqlQuery.list();

}
```

Using `setParameterList` of org.hibernate.SQLQuery,  the list should come with comma in the query like `('Bangalore', 'Hyderabad')`. But its coming without comma in the query like `('Bangalore''Hyderabad')`. That is wrong. Query will not get execute correctly. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is `paramVal` in your code ?

Comment: Sorry. It was values only.

Comment: @AartiJangid are you sure that the exact same `values` which you have declared in 4th line is passed in your method and it's not being enclosed further in a `Map`.

Comment: Yes. It's the same map only.